# nginx with site in a subdir which does not match the ends of url

Tags: nginx, laravel-5

When I try to use laravel PHP framework, I try to place it in a dir called `/home/usr/proj/laravel`, but as we know that the public html of laravel is settled in `/home/usr/proj/laravel/public`, thus my problem is how to make the setting of nginx such that when I access by `mysite.com/laravel/` or `mysite.com/laravel`, we in fact redirected to the location `laravel/public/index.php`.

Also, it seems that there is a rule of nignx which is suggested by the official of laravel, to make the url looks pretty

```
location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

How can I use this in my case?

---

**UPDATE**

It seems the following code works for me (but give me error *NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:*, maybe caused by my router setting)

```
  location /laravel{
    root /home/usr/proj/laravel/public;
    index index.php index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /laravel/public/index.php?$query_string;
  }
```

Comment: you should do try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

Comment: It seems not work also.

Comment: If you see an error from RouteCollection - it sounds like you fixed the problem yourself already :) the rest is in routes.php

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your Update, I think that you should keep your original `try_files` syntax:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

since the location is set to `/laravel` and the root is in the public folder. The way it is currently written ends up looking for file `/home/usr/proj/laravel/public/public/index.php` in the disk.

You should also check to configure your application URL so that it contains the `/location` part of the URL. I am not quite sure about how Laravel 5 is configured since my experience is with Laravel 4.

Comment: It seems we should use alias rather than root